# Microsoft bot framework (NodeJS): Cards in slack

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack, adaptive-cards

I am trying to use a Herocard in Microsoft Bot framework to get a profile overview. This works fine in the emulator:

[image]

However the same herocard in slack is not showing the card. It only shows the text. (don't mind the layout of the text - slack needs * text* to be bold, in the emulator * text* is cursive)

[image]

Here is the code I use to generate the Herocards:

```
heroCard(session, title, subtitle, text, tap) {
    let msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
        .attachments([
            new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .title(title)
                .subtitle(subtitle)
                .text(text)
                .images([
            builder.CardImage.create(session, //google maps static api of a city)
        ])
                .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "I need to change something", "I need to change something"),
            builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "Save Profile", "Save Profile")
        ])
                .tap(tap)
        ]);

    builder.Prompts.text(session, msg);
}
```

I tried to use the channel specific method to make a slack message but this seems to work only with the .NET SDK (or at least I only found documentation on the .NET page)

Lastly I'm also wondering why typings don't work with slack. According to the documentation this should work in slack but only the delay is executed and the sendTyping is not visible.

I'm wondering if I need to activate something in my slack account or something. I used this demo to connect my bot to slack: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-slack

Hoping you guys have some answers,
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, Can you try using an image from url (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards). I think whats happening is when you call the Google maps API to get the image, it makes an async request, but your method doesn't wait for its completion, so it moves forward with creation of card, and once it is created, it sends it to the user. All other data (being textual) is not async, that's why no problem for that.

Comment: Can you share, how you are getting the message? That google API to get image. Just a sample would work.

Comment: Ok I actually must revise my previous comment. When I use a normal image url. The image actually appears. I don't know why it doesn't work with the delay (probably because the aync call is only executed when the url is fired in slack). Thank you very much for this advice. I guess the card border never works in slack? And do you have any idea about the typings by any chance?

Comment: And I'm getting the image via a google url like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + cityName + '&zoom=11&size=500x300&markers=color:red|' + cityName + '&key=' + googleStaticMapsApiKey

Comment: Have you tried specifying the type of format that you receive from the API? Under [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#URL_Parameters) and the subheader Map Parameters, there is the `&format=` parameter that is used for specifying the format you receive. What was the image format of the "normal image url" you used? Also, have you tried using a promise inside of the waterfall step to make sure you have the results from the API call before constructing the card?